# the use of envelope with homogeneous or inhomogeneous summary functions to detect clustering and different results with the simulations

Tags: r, spatstat

I just started to work with spatstat few month ago.
I am trying to detect clustering (and cluster size) of tree seedlings between 2cm and 4 cm in diameter for 15 species on 4 forest plots (250mx250m).

I have 3 covariables (topography, altitude, and opening of the canopy) that show an effect on the density (or intensity). However using cluster model is not possible very probably owing to  a weak clustering giving very different cluster size depending on the methods (This is probably not related to the number of points because for the species with more than 400 points I obtained the same results).

Thus, I used inhomogeneous poisson model with the 3 covariables (mentioned above) known to be important driver of seedling establishment to explain the density/intensity of points (with log quadratic relationships for the quantitative variables and interaction between the co variables).

Then I tried to detect clustering and infer cluster size using monte carlo test based on a  summary function (the pair correlation function). The cluster size will be the maximum distance where the pair correlation computed on the observed points is above the simulations.
  But I am wondering if I should use an inhomogeneous or homogeneous pair correlation function to detect clustering and infer cluster size, since in the book of Baddeley et al. 2015, they use an homogeneous L summary function with inhomogeneous poisson model fit on the data page 398-399.
  I thought if the point process is not homogeneous (which is the case) I should use an inhomogeneous function as a summary function.
Besides, I have very different results depending on the simulations with very different cluster size. Is it because the model is poorly fitted or only because of the method itself?
Is there a better way to measure the size of a cluster ?

If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful!

Regards,

Comment: Usually you shouldn't usually use envelopes of homogeneous summary statistics for inhomogeneous patterns (even though they are mathematically valid) because it is hard to interpret deviations. I don't remember why we did that at the bottom of page 398. I don't completely understand your cluster detection approach. If you really believe it is an inhomogeneous Poisson process you know that the theoretical inhomogeneous pair correlation function is 1 everywhere. Could you provide example code of what you are doing?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response !

Comment: I will try to be more precise about what I want to do.

Comment: I want to measure the clustering of seedlings from different tree species. I want to use the maximum distance where clustering is significant as a measure of the cluster size but I am not sure this is the best approach (I also though about measuring the first max distance when the pair correlation function reach 1 but I thought the use of enveloppe will be more "clean"). Is it more clear ?

Comment: Here is the code I used            Is is a measure of altitude (quantitative) T is the topography (qualitative, with 3 modalities, bottom, top and slope), Pb is the distance from an opening. Because the covariables are not defined everywhere (only very few points, all time less than 1%, it was during the conversion in pixel image), I removed some quadrature points,             for(i in 1: length(LecythisPM10)){

Comment: P=LecythisPM10[[i]]
  Is=Isoline2[[i]]
  T=TOPO1[[i]]
    Pb=PERTURBdistmap[[i]]                                                                       fit2P[[i]]=ppm(P~polynom(Is,2)+T+polynom(Pb,2),sigma=bw.diggle)###
    Z[[i]]=quad.ppm(fit2P[[i]],drop=TRUE)###
    fit2Pgood[[i]] <- ppm(Z[[i]],~polynom(Is,2)+T+polynom(Pb,2),sigma=bw.diggle)   }                                                                                          for(i in 1: 4){
  fit=fitInter2good[[i]]

Comment: ENinhG00[[i]]=envelope(fitInter2good[[i]],pcfinhom,nsim=39,global=TRUE,fix.n=TRUE,correction="best",divisor="d")########### 
}          And after the calculation of the enveloppe, I measure the distance max r where the observed g function is above the simulations. Is it a good approach ?

Comment: The goal at the end is to related the measure of the clustering (a distance) with different measure of disturbance.

Comment: Sorry I just saw that I copy paste the code for the poisson model without the interaction and for the enveloppe with the model including interaction but this is more or less the same code, just the name of the model and the interaction in the model are different.